# Printing counters in nested loops

Tags: java, loops

I'm trying to concatenate counters in nested loops, with the inner loop having a smaller maximum, such that my output should read:

```
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
2.1
2.2
2.3
2.4....
```

Where the inner loop is completing it's cycles and then restarting when the parent loop goes again.

Right now I have

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
public class ForLoop
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/Users/evanlivingston/1.txt", true)));

        for ( int counter = 0; counter <= 15; counter++ )
            out.println( counter );
            for ( int counter2 = 0; counter2 <=4; counter2++)
                out.print( counter2 );
        out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

It seems like I must construct a variable made of variables (the counters) and then print that.

Comment: `for` loops are not nested here as you think so. If you don't keep `{}` with `for`, only one statement after `for` is considered to be under loop.

Comment: If you're using an IDE like Eclipse or NetBeans, tell it to auto-format your code. You'll find that your indentation (the control flow you want) is not the control flow you have actually programmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside the missing nesting, you have to print the outer value in the inner loop:

```
public class ForLoop
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        for (int outer = 0; outer <= 15; ++outer)
            for (int inner = 0; inner <=4; ++inner)
                System.out.println (outer + "." + inner);
    }
}
```

But since each expression is only one line, we can omit the curly braces here. :) (More precise: The 2nd for loop consists of 2 lines, but the second is covered by the first, so it is one expression for the outer 'for'.

For loops, you normally use i and j. If not, take more reasonable names than `counter`, which is an implementation detail, instead of a semantic name.

Answer (score 3):

It is not always a good idea to use for loops without braces:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
public class ForLoop
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/Users/evanlivingston/1.txt", true)));

        String output = "";
        for ( int counter = 1; counter < 16; counter++ ) {
            output = Integer.toString(counter) + ".";
            for ( int counter2 = 1; counter2 < 5; counter2++) {
                out.print(test + Integer.toString(counter2) + "\n");
            }
        }
        out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't use braces around your for statements, only the next line of the for statement is used in the loop. So your for loops are not really nested.

Comment: Parentheses are round brackets. I think you were talking of braces.

Comment: That's true. I'm not so talented in English, but I corrected it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that your for-loops aren't nested. Bugs such as these are the reason every coding standard for Java I have even seen mandates the use of `{` and `}` to indicate with statements should be executed for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider a number of things:

- Always format your code appropriately. It reduces the likelyhood that you will make a mistake in determining code flow.
- Always make sure you are closing your handles. A good practice for this is to always put the close() in a finally block, to ensure it gets called no matter what. Alternatively, if you're using C#, just use the using() {} construct to do this for you.
- Numerical calculation tends to be faster than string concatenation, especially at scale.

Here's an alternative solution to the ones presented:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    PrintWriter out = null;

    try {

        out = new PrintWriter(
            new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(yourFileName, true)));

        for ( float i = 1.0F; i < 16; i += 0.1F) {
            out.println(String.format("%.1f", i));
            if(i >= (((int)i) + 0.4))
            {
                i += 0.5;
            }
        }

    } finally {
        if(out != null)
        {
            out.close();
        }
    }

}
```